# Changing OpenVPN device name

Tags: openvpn

I have multiple VPN server software running on the same server, two of them (tinc and openvpn) are using the same `/dev/net/tun` devices and spawning a tunX iface.

The later started ones will use tun devices from *zero*, so they're reusing each other's device and causing a lot of problems and disruption of services.

My question is, is it possible to let OpenVPN to spawn its own tun with other names like tun-X or otun-Y etc?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `dev` option to specify which device you want to use. You'll also have to add `dev-type` to specify tun or tap:

```
dev ovpn-tcp
dev-type tun
```

Will use a tun device named `ovpn-tcp`, giving you:

```
$ ip link ls ovpn-tcp
7: ovpn-tcp: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 100
    link/none
```

This is quite useful—far easier to hang, e.g., `iptables` rules off of known device names.